# I am facing problem with my python software while using firebase for data storage

Tags: python, firebase

i am just new to python and while i made a software that manages inventory using barcode no. i am facing issue while using firebase realtime data base for storing my json file, i did it yesterday and it was working fine but now when i am setting data in firebase using set method, its getting set but when i am getting the data from firebase it is showing data as null, also the data format that i am uploading is json an yesterday it was working fine but i dont know what messed up today, i tried everything but its not working.

my_code:-

```
def set_to_firebase():
    with open("on_of.txt", mode="r") as new_file_text:
        data=new_file_text.readline()
        is_on=data
    file_size_on = os.path.getsize("on_of.txt")
    if file_size_on==0:
        pass
    else:
        if is_on=="False":
            with open("data.json", "r") as f:
                file = json.load(f)
            ref.delete()
            ref.set(file)
        elif is_on=="True":
            pass



def get_real_data():
    with open("on_of.txt", mode="r") as new_file_text:
        data=new_file_text.readline()
        is_on=data

    if is_on=="False":
        file_new_json = ref.get()
        with open("data.json", mode="w") as new_file_data:
            json.dump(file_new_json, new_file_data, indent=4)
    elif is_on=="True":
        pass
```

my json file :-
{
"1": {
"name": "hjghjghj",
"weaver": "hygjghyghj",
"qty": 1,
"image": "C:/Users/mayru/Desktop/file/41+lVas4jtL.bmp",
"date_time": "29/05/2022 19:53:35"
},
"2": {
"name": "o[op[",
"weaver": "p[;oip",
"qty": 1,
"image": "C:/Users/mayru/Desktop/file/10 (1).jpg",
"date_time": "29/05/2022 19:54:18"
}
}

also yesterday it worked fine but today its showing this issue :-

```
[
    null,
    {
        "date_time": "29/05/2022 19:53:35",
        "image": "C:/Users/mayru/Desktop/file/41+lVas4jtL.bmp",
        "name": "hjghjghj",
        "qty": 1,
        "weaver": "hygjghyghj"
    },
    {
        "date_time": "29/05/2022 19:54:18",
        "image": "C:/Users/mayru/Desktop/file/10 (1).jpg",
        "name": "o[op[",
        "qty": 1,
        "weaver": "p[;oip"
    }
]
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: No, i am not getting any error message, the only problem i am facing is when i am getting the data from firebase using get(), it getting me back the data with null in place of the key for the dictionary, also it worked fine yesterday, was working smoothly, but now suddenly its showing null in place of my key